# Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using firebase phone auth with invisible ReCaptcha. I have set captcha property size to invisible and also used id of HTML button.

But every time user enters mobile number I am getting the following error

> Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

**EDIT** This error is occurring when I hide the sign-in-button which has set with ReCaptcha (in my case button with id="send").

Any idea why this is happening?

I am not getting what went wrong.

Thank you in advance
.html

```
<div>

        <ion-label > Enter your mobile number </ion-label>

        <ion-item>
         +91 | &nbsp;   <ion-input type="tel" [formControl] = "mobile_no" ></ion-input>

        </ion-item>
        <ion-button id="send" [disabled] = "mobile_no.invalid" (click)="send( mobile_no.value)">Continue</ion-button>
      </div>   

<ion-button (click) ="verify(otpArray)">Submit</ion-button> // submit otp. otpArray contains otp
```

.ts

```
send(mobile_no){

    let mobile = '+91' + mobile_no
    console.log(mobile)

    const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('send', {
       'size': 'invisible',
     });

    this.response.linkWithPhoneNumber( mobile, appVerifier).then(data => { // response contains response after Gmail login

      if(data){


        console.log(this.result)
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })    


   }

   verify(otp){

    console.log(otp)

    this.code = otp.first + otp.second + otp.third + otp.fourth + otp.fifth + otp.sixth
    console.log(this.code)


     this.result.confirm(this.code).then(result => {
       var user = result.user;
       console.log(result)
     }).catch(function (err) {console.log(err)} )

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are at some point hiding a block with id = "send". But you do it too soon. Transfer id = "send" hiding logic to an explanation

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': (response) => {
    hiddenButtonBlock(); // Here
  }
});
```